# Javascript switch keys for a hash

Tags: javascript

Is there an equivalent method available in javascript to switch keys in a hash

For example

`Eg. {x: 50, y: 75, data: 99}, to {x: 50, y: 99, data: 75}`

Comment: `Object.keys` gets you the keys.  How you switch them is another story.  What's the Ruby equivalent of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't think there is a ruby equivalent to swap keys, it would have to be iteratively as far as I know. This method allows you to modify the key value.

Comment: This appears to just be a specialization of "how to swap to variables". Your ruby example isn't relevant since you don't actually want to `transform_keys`, you want to swap values between two *specific* keys without affecting other keys in the object. You're just after `var tmp = obj.y; obj.y = obj.x; obj.x = tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use reduce

```
hash = { name: 'Rob', age: '28' }

Object.keys(hash).reduce((object, key) => {

    object[key.toUpperCase()] = hash[key];

    console.log(object);

    return object;
}, {});
```

Basically, what is happening is I iterate over an array of the hash object's keys. For each key, I alter an empty object (the last argument), declaring that key with the required transformations as a property on that object and then assigning it the value of the corresponding property on the hash object. The altered object is then used in place of the initial empty object, and the function calls itself recursively until the end of the array. Reduce is awesome and if you're new to JS I highly suggest learning more about it! All of the functional array methods (map, filter, reduce, forEach) are worth looking into.

Read more about reduce here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a

You're going to have to write a function to swap object keys

```
const propSwap = (obj1, key1, key2, obj2) => {
    obj2 = obj2 || JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));

    obj1[key2] = obj2[key1];

    obj1[key1] = obj2[key2];

    return obj1;
}
```

that first line makes it so that obj2 is an optional argument

unfortunately the javascript standard library isn't extremely deep but you can accomplish those two operations separately using the methods I've outlined above. If you have any questions let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const transformed = Object.entries(hash).reduce((aggr, [key, value]) => {
    aggr[key.toUpperCase()] = value;

    return aggr;
}, {});
```